# Error while installing tui-editor or ngx-tui-editor

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install toast markdown editor and getting following error

```
npm i --save tui-editor
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/sohee-lee7/Squire.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ramesh Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-25T04_19_47_296Z-debug.log
```

My 2019-05-25T04_19_47_296Z-debug.log file [debug.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N1zRYdU9Ojqj22py2i1WGimWYh6IHs3t)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by

1. Install [Git](https://gitforwindows.org/)
2. Add path to C:\Program Files\Git\bin C:\Program Files\Git\cmd in
   PATH environment variable.
3. Restart the computer

run command

```
npm i --save tui-editor
npm i --save ngx-tui-editor
```